# How can I have a node that refers to another node in database Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want create two nodes ,

- Node Regions that contains a specific cities.
- Node Cities which belongs to specific Region.

Usually in SQL we create table Regions with `id_region(PRIMARY KEY), name_region` , and we create table cities with `id_cities (PRIMARY KEY), name_cities,id_region`, so like that, we refer to region table with its id.

How can I dot that on firebase Database.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
root: {
  cities: {
    $city_1: {
      region: $region_1
    },
    $city_2: {
      region: $region_1
    }
  },
  regions: {
    $region_1: {
      cities: {
        $city_1: true,  // This node can have any value really just as long as the key refers to $city_1
        $city_2: true   // Same
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me try it, I'm going to populate spinner1 with regions, and spinner2 with cities.

Comment: Yes ,It works. For more explanation , I refer to [https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data]  Category: Create Data that scale.